# Web GPU Call Stack Limit - Have to Expand function manually

Tags: javascript, web, gpu, webgpu, wgsl

[image: image of the function definition commented out and the expanded form working]

Using the newest chrome 113 and the web gpu function, after updating drivers, testing on different computers, I have determined that this is the error, and I cannot understand why wgsl would fail here.  Speculation: there's some call stack limit im hitting that is not mentioned the documentation?  I thought id share these findings I don't have an answer though

Comment: It's getting a device lost, I'm assuming that's what gpu disconnected is referring too? Can you file a bug at crbug.com/tint with repro steps and the OS/GPU in use?